# How to fix implicit type decalration of function in C for android kernel

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel

I was trying to build an Android kernel for my device (Moto G 2014 aka titan) and after I added a custom governor "Yankactive", I keep getting this error and I have no idea on how to fix this error.

Here is the error:

```
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_yankactive.c: In function 'cpufreq_yankactive_timer_resched':
drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_yankactive.c:166:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'get_cpu_idle_time' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   get_cpu_idle_time(smp_processor_id(),
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:308: drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_yankactive.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:443: drivers/cpufreq] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:965: drivers] Error 2
```

Here is the source code file of the governor I used: http://hastebin.com/vefequzema.pl

Comment: You have code that uses the function `get_cpu_idle_time` before actually declaring it. Either define the function at a point before the calling code or put a forward declaration. See for instance [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245284/error-implicit-declaration-of-function-on-all-my-functions), there are many other good answers if you search for the error.

Comment: @sagar846 Which exactly kernel you are trying to build? Please provide version and link, if possible.

Comment: @SamProtsenko I'm trying to build the CM 13 version 3.4.X for my device : titan (Motorola Moto G2). Here is the link to the repo : https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_motorola_msm8226

Comment: @sagar846 `get_cpu_idle_time()` function was made external in kernel 3.8: [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.8&i=get_cpu_idle_time). So you need to use k3.8 or later, and also add `#include "cpufreq_governor.h"` line at the top of your driver. If you want to use your driver with k3.4 (which you are using right now), you need to make `get_cpu_idle_time()` function external manually, before trying to build your driver.

Answer (score 0):

Your governor call the get_cpu_idle_time() function which is not defined in the file you added. 
Take a look at this commit
[GitHub](https://github.com/CertifiedBlyndGuy/kernel_oneplus_onyx/commit/970a98bfe141a617a8bc54833ca379286fda4986)